# Проверить если ли в коде классы, строки, массивы

Tags: c#, .net, синтаксический-анализ

На вход подается код в виде текста. Как проверить код на наличиe в нем классов, работы со строками или работы с массивом(любые действие)?

Наример, файл с исходным кодом на вход:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            bool bo = false;
            object n = 45;
            object[] x = new object[] { 80, 117, 115, 104, 45, 85, 112, 115};
            x.item
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                x[i].ItemsEqual(a2)
                if (x[i] == n)
                {

                    bo = true;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(bo);
        }
   }
}
```

В данном коде есть работа с массивом.

Как можно организовать такую проверку?

Comment: Я студент, а не преподаватель и не выбираю себе заданий.

Comment: @Kisa777 опишите вопрос более детально. вы сами хотите реализовать статический анализатор кода?

Comment: Верно все) Хочу реализовать статический анализ кода. Но как лучше сделать не знаю. Думаю что можно регулярками пойти.

Comment: @Kisa777 нажмите на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/809884/edit) и дополните ответ более четкими критериями. например, проверна на принцыпы ООП. проверка на наличие массива и т.п. 
Когда вопрос будет четким, тогда можно уже дать ответ

Comment: if( [stringCodeFile.IndexOf (stringKeyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) > 0 ){...};

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно считается за «работу с массивом»: объявление массива, инициализация, обращение по индексу, любое обращение?

Comment: любые действие)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас на самом деле довольно сложное задание. Но в современном C# есть инструменты, которые облегчат вам его. Например, вы можете воспользоваться Roslyn API.

Давайте напишем простой пример, на основе которого вы сможете добавлять нужную функциональность.

Итак, для начала создадим консольный проект на C#, назовём его HelloWorld, и положим туда такой вот код:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] strings = { "Hello ", "world" };
            foreach (var s in strings)
                Console.Write(s);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Этот проект мы будем использовать как тестовый для нашего анализатора.
Целью нашего анализатора будет найти, что переменная `s` на самом деле имеет тип `string`.

Создадим проект самого анализатора. Для этого поставьте Roslyn SDK через Visual Studio Installer:

[image: Roslyn SDK, без него никак в нашем мире]

Теперь, в Visual Studio появится проект типа «Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool». Создаём его.

[image: и проект тоже я сломал?]

Затем, зайдём в Dependencies → Manage NuGet Packages, обязательно обновим пакеты до последней версии и доустановим Microsoft.Tpl.DataFlow (без него у меня не работает, и это, кажется, известный баг).

[image: Отака фигня, малята]

Теперь, собственно наш анализатор.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace CodeAnalyzer
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            // подправьте путь на путь к вашему solution'у
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"D:\HelloWorld.sln");
            // у нас только один проект
            var project = solution.Projects.Single();
            var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

            // для каждого из файлов в проекте у нас отдельное синтаксическое дерево
            // даже в пустом проекте их несколько, например, AssemblyInfo.cs
            foreach (var syntaxTree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
            {
                var root = await syntaxTree.GetRootAsync();
                // создаём семантический анализатор
                var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
                // получаем все типы переменных
                foreach (var type in GetVariableTypes(root))
                {
                    // спрашиваем у анализатора, что это за тип
                    var typeSymbol = (ITypeSymbol)model.GetSymbolInfo(type).Symbol;
                    // проверяем, не строка ли это
                    if (typeSymbol.Name == "String" &&
                        typeSymbol.ContainingNamespace?.Name == "System" &&
                        typeSymbol.ContainingAssembly?.Name == "mscorlib")
                    {
                        // если да, выдаём положение этой строки в исходниках
                        var position = type.GetLocation().GetLineSpan();
                        Console.WriteLine($"String is used, location = {position}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // этот вспомогательный метод получает типы всех локальных переменных
        static IEnumerable<TypeSyntax> GetVariableTypes(SyntaxNode root)
        {
            // получаем декларации переменных
            var localVariableTypes =
                    root.DescendantNodes()
                        .OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>()
                        .Select(decl => decl.Type);
            // не забываем foreach, он почему-то отдельно
            var foreachVariableTypes =
                    root.DescendantNodes()
                        .OfType<ForEachStatementSyntax>()
                        .Select(decl => decl.Type);
            return localVariableTypes.Concat(foreachVariableTypes);
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаем на нашем тестовом проекте, получаем:

> ```
> String is used, location = D:\HelloWorld\Program.cs: (9,21)-(9,24)
> ```

Литература:

- [Документация на семантический анализ Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Semantic-Analysis).
- [А здесь можно посмотреть синтаксическое дерево](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxNGAfAAgBgARYCMA3ALABQFAdhGHFAA4QDGceAEnADZcD2A6rwRcAJhQDeFPNIIAmAoQDsUmZPIyNCgGwEALAoAcACiI4A2gF08EBAHMoAShWa8aly9OWFOKHgC8rngARJw8vMFIwQDuQqJBeAC+ZOruGgBmQnAsABZ4RgBuNni+AJZU3o7OqZoAwrxUULxccAB0/Agl8EaOydUyRACcRg697glV4+QJQA).

---

Небольшое дополнение. Вы не можете узнать, какие типы используются в классе, по одному только тексту файла. Например, если у вас в соседнем файле есть такое определение:

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    struct String
    {
        public static implicit operator String(System.String s) => default;
    }
}
```

то ваш код

```
String s = "";
Console.WriteLine(s.GetType());
```

выдаст не `System.String`, а `HelloWorld.String`. Именно поэтому для правильного анализа нужен не текст, а весь проект.

Comment: Ого... отличный ответ :D

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Спасибо! Я старался

Comment: @VladD, а как он определяет какой язык парсит? он только из известных может?

Comment: @Grundy: Угу. У Roslyn-овских классов кое-где даже есть свойство, показывающее, на каком языке тот или иной кусок.

Comment: @VladD, а свой можно добавлять?

Comment: @Grundy: А ещё `LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax` на самом деле `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax`.

Comment: @Grundy: Можно, конечно, исходники на гитхабе есть :D

Comment: @VladD, ну не :-) исходники на гитхабе не интересно :-) я думал там унаследовать что-то или интерфейс реализовать какой-нить и все :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, в любом случае придётся писать синтаксический анализатор языка, как-то описывать грамматику и фсё такоэ.

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант, скомпилировать код, загрузить полученную сборку и через *Reflection* проверить типы полей и локальных переменных. Если считать, что код использует массивы, когда в нем есть хотя бы одно поле или локальная переменная с типом, унаследованным от *Array*, как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
    class Program
    {
        //отображает информацию о использовании строк и массивов в сборке
        public static string GetAssInfo(Assembly ass)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);
            Type type;

            List<string> arrays = new List<string>();
            List<string> strings = new List<string>();

            //анализируем типы сборки
            foreach (TypeInfo t in ass.DefinedTypes)
            {

                foreach (var mem in t.DeclaredMembers)
                {
                    switch (mem.MemberType)
                    {
                        case MemberTypes.Field:
                            type = (mem as FieldInfo).FieldType;
                            if (type.BaseType == typeof(Array))
                            {
                                arrays.Add(t.ToString() + ", поле " + type.ToString() + " " + mem.Name);
                            }

                            if (type == typeof(string))
                            {
                                strings.Add(t.ToString() + ", поле " + type.ToString() + " " + mem.Name);
                            }

                            break;
                        case MemberTypes.Method:

                            MethodInfo mi = (mem as MethodInfo);
                            var body = mi.GetMethodBody();
                            foreach (var local in body.LocalVariables)
                            {
                                if (local.LocalType.BaseType == typeof(Array))
                                {
                                    arrays.Add(t.ToString() + ", метод " + mi.Name + ", переменная " + local.ToString());
                                }

                                if (local.LocalType == typeof(string))
                                {
                                    strings.Add(t.ToString() + ", метод " + mi.Name + ", переменная " + local.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                    }

                }

            }

            //выводим информацию
            sb.AppendLine("Найдено использований массивов: " + arrays.Count.ToString());    

            foreach (var s in arrays)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("- " + s);
            }
            sb.AppendLine();

            sb.AppendLine("Найдено использований строк: " + strings.Count.ToString());
            foreach (var s in strings)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("- " + s);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            //путь к файлу с исходным кодом должен быть передан первым аргументом
            if(argv.Length==0){Console.WriteLine("Укажите файл с исходым кодом");return;}

            var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            string source = File.ReadAllText(argv[0]);            
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.dll", true);

            //компилируем сборку из кода
            CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,source);
            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Не удалось скомпилировать код");
                foreach (var err in results.Errors)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
                }
                return;
            }

            //выводим информацию
            string s = GetAssInfo(results.CompiledAssembly);

            Console.WriteLine("* Информация о сборке: *");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine(s);             

        }       
    }        
}
```

Недостаток способа в том, что при этом сборка грузится в память процесса и от нее никак нельзя избавиться до завершения работы программы (кроме выгрузки всего домена приложений). Также, он является небезопасным, так как позволяет выполнить вредоносный код, если он будет во входном файле.

Comment: +1, но: разве через рефлексию можно получить доступ к _локальным_ переменным?

Comment: @VladD Ну, [MethodBody.LocalVariables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.methodbody.localvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), вроде работает. Возвращает информацию о типе, но не имя.

Comment: Ого, круто, спасибо!

Comment: А компилятор локальные переменные не выбросит? Хотя, массивы-то, наверное, точно не выбросит... // @VladD

Comment: @АндрейNOP При компиляции со включенной отладочной информацией не должен выбрасывать.

Comment: Локальная переменная _может_ превратиться в поле на IL-уровне: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACh0tsBWA4gZiwCYMBhIgbyI3axpQA4sA2DAFkAFAEo2HVoQ4zSmKBgC8GAEQALOABtNAewwB3HQk0ATFZVkcUATn4A6ACJaIAT2FpRFy6WvConiXYAXyIgoA

Comment: А также компилятор может добавить скрытую локальную переменную: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEDMACFAmDBhAWACgBvYjCrTFAFgwFkAKASwDsYNmAaT9jAKwCU5SmSKUJGFjyEYAvFP49mggNwiKAX2KagA==