# Как получить список всех вызываемых методов в коде C# Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Как получить список всех используемых. Например

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String s = "sasdad";
            s.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
        }
    }
}
```

Получить ToString.

Comment: Отличный вопрос! Я напишу ответ в понедельник, когда доберусь до компа (если никто не успеет до меня).

Comment: Можно как-то с вами связаться ?)

Comment: До понедельника никак, я в отпуске :)

Comment: А после понидельника ?)

Comment: @VladD не там вы отпуск проводите )

Comment: @Kisa777: После понедельника я доступен на сайте :)

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ну это короткий, пару дней :)

Comment: @VladD так и никто не дал ответ, надежда на Вас)

Comment: @Kisa777: Угу, сейчас напишу.

Comment: @VladD, а ты вроде на подобный отвечал уже? [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810044/186999) да, немного отличается.

Comment: @Grundy: Это по сути follow-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Делаем вот как. Для начала создадим анализатор, как описано в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810044/10105).

Нам нужно получить все вызовы методов, и вывести их. Это делается напрямую так:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
// подставьте путь к вашему проекту
var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"D:\HelloWorld.sln");
var project = solution.Projects.Single();
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

// обходим все деревья (то есть, все файлы)
foreach (var syntaxTree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
{
    var root = await syntaxTree.GetRootAsync();
    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
    // получаем всё, что выглядеит как вызов метода
    var invocations = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
    foreach (var invocation in invocations)
    {
        var expression = invocation.Expression;
        // спрашиваем у семантического анализатора о типе выражения
        var symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(expression).Symbol;
        if (symbol.Kind != SymbolKind.Method)
            continue;
        // выясняем дополнительнуыю информацию
        bool isStatic = symbol.IsStatic;
        var name = symbol.Name;
        var containingTypeName = symbol.ContainingType.ToDisplayString();
        var location = invocation.GetLocation().GetLineSpan();
        // и выводим
        Console.WriteLine($"{(isStatic ? "Static" : "Non-static")} call," +
            $" type = {containingTypeName}, method = {name}, location = {location}");
    }
}
```

Например, для вот такого тестового кода:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static string g = string.Empty;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] strings = { "Hello ", "world" };
            foreach (var s in strings)
                Console.Write(s.ToString() + s?.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(strings[i].ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

получаем результат:

```
Static call, type = System.Console, method = Write, location = Program.cs: (11,16)-(11,59)
Non-static call, type = string, method = ToString, location = Program.cs: (11,30)-(11,42)
Non-static call, type = string, method = ToString, location = Program.cs: (11,47)-(11,58)
Static call, type = System.Console, method = Write, location = Program.cs: (13,16)-(13,41)
Non-static call, type = string, method = ToUpper, location = Program.cs: (13,30)-(13,50)
Static call, type = System.Console, method = WriteLine, location = Program.cs: (14,12)-(14,31)
```

Comment: А что у него в качестве root выступает? Я что-то себе слабо представляют это дерево для класса :)

Comment: @Grundy: Целый файл.

Comment: @VladD, а если вместо массива строк использовать список (List), то вызовы метода Add тоже покажет? `var strings = new List<string> { "Hello ", "world" };`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Нет, синкаксически это ж не вызов. А то, что там под капотом скрытый вызов, это совсем другая история.

Comment: Разве? Я думал это просто сахар и он преобразуется в последовательность вызовов `Add`... Как Linq-выражения запросов

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Это внутри, под капотом. Точно так же как и LINQ.

Comment: @VladD, все равно сомневаюсь. Здесь тоже не будет видно вызовов Add: https://pastebin.com/XVWSsg0b ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Конечно. С точки зрения синтаксиса, это `CollectionInitializerExpresion`. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxNGAfAAgBgARYCMA3ALABQuBhAdAMID2ANk3AMYwCWDAdlGeQpYATNQDsFAN4U8s6gDYCAFmoAOABREcAbQC6eCAgDmUAJQy508nJt4AbobxQArmEgwGCPAF48POADueADKru6eeJJ4hDhI0QCsccL4AL4CtnJEAJzqLm4QHgg0AEpwLkwwpukZeIx8zHAlcBAAJgDScACe6lUWsikUA9ZCoqH5hXgg1ADMUn0E03icPDB4peWrUUZwMMR4AA4InA7wTjt7QzZYi1gqAIItLerLq2BwYMCIpj4AfGtlzgqeAA1L43h9ENVZNc8ABJACiPFciAKEQA4jtEciEKiED1fngYAALBAMIL+IIAOQYMFC+32nngLXhAA82HB9lxeD0BCkgA=

Comment: @VladD, ок, я понял. Это просто синтаксический разбор на выражения.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Плюс семантический анализ поверх. Если хочется, можно отыскать все инициализаторы.