# Поиск переменных по текстовому файлу и приравнивание их в программе существующим переменным

Tags: c#

Существует файл "123.txt", в котором написано следующее:

```
namespace Variable
{
class VariableEdit
 {
  public const int abc = 123
 }
}
```

В программе существует такая же переменная abc. Нужно прочитать файл (123.txt), найти переменную эту в файле (abc) и записать её значение в программу (переменная в программе: abc).
Я пока что нашёл только такой код, чтобы найти строку, в которой есть данная переменная abc

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + $"/123.txt", Encoding.Default);
while (!str.EndOfStream)
{
 string st = str.ReadLine();
 if (st.StartsWith("abcToProgramm")) //переменная, которая в программе написана
 {
  Variable.abc = st; //класс Variable, в котором существует данная переменная
  break;
 }
}
```

Но в данном случае копируется вся строка, в мне нужно только значение. Помогите, пожалуйста. Если что, ниже тот самый класс, который написан в программе:

```
namespace Variable
{
 public static class Variable
 {
  public const int abc;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно попробовать

```csharp
string text = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + $"/123.txt");
string search = "abc =";
text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(search) + search.Length);
text = text.Remove(text.IndexOf("\r\n")); // \r\n - перенос строки
if (text.Contains(";")) text = text.Remove(text.IndexOf(";"));
if (int.TryParse(text.Trim(), out int num))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Найдено abc: " + num);
    Variable.abc = num;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("abc не найдено");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! А можно как-то число "5" во второй строке вычислять автоматически? Например, сделать метод, в котором во второй строке: text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(переменная на вход в методе) + количество символов в переменной на входе);

Comment: @Frehzy обновил код

Comment: Я только что посидел и сам точно такой же код написал. Спасибо огромное. Как же сложно начинать учить язык программирования...

Answer (score 0):

```
...

if (st.Trim().StartsWith("public const int abc")) //переменная, которая в программе написана
{
  var index = st.Trim().LastIndexOf("public const int abc = ");
  Variable.abc = int.Parse(st.Substring(index).Trim());
  break;
}
...
```

Так же рекомендую почитать про то как работать с строками в c#.
Пример выше решает вашу задачу в лоб и не оптимален, применив это решение вы возможно сможете сформулировать свой вопрос в более общем виде.

Comment: Немного переписал программу, но по итогу выводит вот такую ошибку: https://ibb.co/sF7t829

Comment: @Frehzy исключение возниаает, когда преобразовать строку в число не получилось. Там точно в строке целое число и нет постороннего мусора?

Comment: Да. На скриншоте показал файл, из которого нужно взять переменную. Пробовал убирать ";", но он всё равно выдаёт это исключение

Comment: Я не стал отсекать `;` так как в вопросе у вас её не было, вынесите результат работы функции `st.Substring(index).Trim()` в переменную и в режиме debug посмотрите на ее содержание.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще для таких целей есть специальные методы по разбору CS кода, одним из примеров могу посоветовать [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/809884/220553) ответ.

Но если вам все же нужно разбивать этот файл как строку, то можно использовать "всемогущий" LINQ, ибо достаточно найти ключевые аспекты, по которым надо сделать поиск. У вас это `строка`, `знак =` и также `знак ;` (который должен быть в конце строки, но у вас почему-то его нет).

Имея это делаем примерно следующее:

```
var findValue = File.ReadAllLines("Test.txt")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("abc"))?
    .Split(new[] { '=', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .LastOrDefault();

if (int.TryParse(findValue, out int result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

- `File.ReadAllLines("Test.txt")` - читаем файл как массив строк.
- `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("abc"))` - из полученного файла берем ту строку, которая содержит `abc`. Тут есть пару но - если у вас надо найти определенный тип, то стоит дописать условие, если таких переменных много и они расположены в разных методах например, то тоже придется дописать! Данный вариант просто берет строку в надежде, что она у нас одна.
- `?` - Если предыдущий вызов не дал `NULL`, то мы выполняем код дальше, иначе пропускаем и выдаем `NULL` в результат.
- `.Split(new[] { '=', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - разбиваем полученную строку по `=` и `;` - это даст нам строковой массив, где первым значением будет все до `=`, вторым все после (но до `;`), а 3-м все после `;`. Так, как после `;` обычно у нас пустота (я надеюсь, что она у вас там), то мы убираем эту пустоту при помощи `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.
- `.LastOrDefault();` - берем из полученного массива последнее значение. Если у вас после `;` есть что-то еще, то тут строит наверно брать 2-е значение (то, что строго после `=`).

В `findValue` у нас будет `string` значение с необходимым числом, либо `NULL`, если такого нет. Остается нам это число преобразовать в правильный формат, `int` и делает это

```
int.TryParse(findValue, out int result)
```

Он вернет нам `bool` значение, где `true` - удалось преобразовать, а `false` - нет. Само значение он отдаст через `out`.